# VueJS: отвязать атрибут input max от данных (не пересчитывать значение)

Tags: vue.js

Задача: на VueJS сделать `<input type="number">`, который можно корректировать только в сторону уменьшения от исходного значения `myval`. Я сделал это через атрибут `max`:

```
<input type="number" min="0" :max="myval" v-model="myval" class="form-control">
```

Загвоздка в том, что `:max="myval"` привязывает значение к `myval`, к которому также прибиндено значение `v-model="myval"`.

Получается так:

- начальное значение `myval == 100`, `max="100"`
- уменьшаем на "1": `myval == 99`, => также пересчитывается и максимальное значение: `max="99"`.
- теперь нельзя "увеличить назад" до 100

[Пример на Сodepen](https://codepen.io/jsfun/pen/Pdwgyy)

Конечно, можно добавить еще одну переменную, но... есть ли другие способы?

Comment: `:max.prop="myval"`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Нет, то же самое

Comment: какой сложный вопрос то оказался) в angularjs это было стандартно и просто, во vue нашелся аттрибут `v-once`, который ставится на элемент. это работает, и v-model остается, но например класс видимо уже не получится изменить – https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeazeL

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, спасибо работает!

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, напишите в виде ответа, я помечу как решение.